# Generic collection mapping using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

If any class implements the `IEnumerable` interface at some stage in its hierarchy is it possible to to create a collection and populate that class?

I'm wanting to write a simple function that if it takes an object that implements either `IList<>`, `ICollection<>`, `IEnumerable<>` etc or is an `Array` (so all at some stage implements `IEnumerable`) that I can populate it with a collection of values.

So this function doesn't know if it will receive a `List<object>` or `object[]` but will be able to populate both.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't populate _IEnumerable<>_ in general. This is why _IList<>_ and _ICollection<>_ exist. But you can check if the __IEnumerable<>_ implement _ICollection<>_ or _IList<>_ and then populate it if it's the case.

Comment: Do you want to write a function that *takes* any IEnumerable to fill some other (known) collection, or do you actually want to take an IEnumerable to fill itself with more values?

Comment: You can't. For example IEnumerable can also be an interface behind readonly collections... you can't populate those...

Comment: @poke The latter, I want to take an empty IEnumerable and populate it with more values. Realistically speaking you'd pass the Type that is IEnumerable and I'll create a populated instance of it with the values.

Answer (score 0):

The [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface only specifies a method that gives you an enumerator to enumerate over the object’s items. As such there is no information about what the object’s other abilities is. So you cannot tell if the amount of items is fixed, or mutable or even mutable from the outside.

The first interface to supply this is [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) which, in addition to the random access, provides methods to add objects. Just because you have an IList it does not mean you have write access to it though, as ILists can be read-only. There is also [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) which specifies add methods for dictionary-like objects. All other standard collections usually do not implement an interface that gives you this ability.

So, you cannot fill an arbitrary collection with values without knowing its implementation, or at least a more specific implementation detail (IList or IDictionary).

> I don't need catch all functionality I just need something to cover most instances. So if IEnumerable, ICollection or IList are passed then I can just return a list.

If you get either an `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, you also have an `IEnumerable<T>` (because both implement it), so you just have a single case. You can just accept an IEnumerable and create a list based on it:

```
public IList<T> CreateList<T> (IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>(enumerable);

    // add custom items
    list.Add(GetCustomItem<T>());

    return list;
}
```

If you like, you can also then make a version which is non-generic by just removing all the `<T>`s from the definition.

Comment: I don't need catch all functionality I just need something to cover most instances. So if IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T> or IList<T> are passed then I can just return a list. What I am trying to cater to is the potential for custom collections but all I want to enforce is that thet at some stage implement IEnumerable. I could take that a level up to be ICollection.

Comment: If you just want to return a list, you could just create one in your function, add all the items from the IEnumerable, then add your items and return it as an IList.